# Density of final states in photon absorption/emission by a hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, absorption, photon-emission, density-of-states

Consider a hydrogen atom in an electromagnetic field. The Hamiltonian is of the form

$$\hat{H}=\underbrace{\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+V(r)}_{\text{atom}}+\underbrace{\sum_{\vec{k},\sigma}\hbar cka^{\dagger}_{\vec{k},\sigma}a_{\vec{k},\sigma}}_\text{radiation}+\underbrace{\hat{H}_1+\hat{H}_2}_{\text{interaction}}.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
In first order perturbation theory, only the $\hat{H}_1$ piece in the interaction part contributes to transition amplitudes. Let me consider the case of emission first.

### Notation

- $\lvert\nu_\text{Atom}\rangle\rightarrow$ hydrogen state with energy eigenvalue $\epsilon_\nu$;
- $\lvert1_{\vec{k},\sigma}\rangle$ and $\lvert\boldsymbol{0}\rangle\rightarrow$ one $(\vec{k},\sigma)$ photon and the electromagnetic vacuum state respectively;
- $E_i$ and $E_f\rightarrow$*total* initial and final energy.

**Note**: I'm considering the atomic states in the transition to be *assigned* and the photon frequency to be determined by the arising conditions.$^1$

### Emission

$$\lvert i\rangle=\lvert\boldsymbol{0}\rangle\otimes\lvert\alpha_\text{Atom}\rangle\longrightarrow\lvert f\rangle=\lvert1_{\vec{k},\sigma}\rangle\otimes\lvert{\beta_{\text{atom}}\rangle}\label{2}\tag{emission of a photon}$$
Although the atom has a discrete spectrum and I'm only considering the two levels involved in the atomic transition, there is a photon in the final state, so the photonic density of *final* states  (DoS) is
$$\rho_f(\hbar\omega_k)=\frac{V}{2\pi^2\hbar c}\omega_k^2d\Omega\label{3}\tag{DoS #1}$$
This only considers the photonic energy, so the condition $E_f=E_i$ in Fermi Golden rule easily becomes $\omega_k=\frac{E_\beta-E_\alpha}{\hbar}$ and the transition rate per unit solid angle is
$$R_{i\to f}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\lvert\langle f\lvert\hat{H}_1\rvert i\rangle\rvert^2\rho_f(\hbar\omega_k)\bigg\rvert_{\omega_k=\frac{E_\beta-E_\alpha}{\hbar}}\label{4}\tag{transition rate #1}.$$
This works fine.

### Absorption

Nevertheless, in the case of absorption I have a problem with the DoS.

$$\lvert i\rangle=\lvert 1_{\vec{k},\sigma}\rangle\otimes\lvert\beta _\text{Atom}\rangle\longrightarrow\lvert f\rangle=\lvert\boldsymbol{0}\rangle\otimes\lvert{\alpha_{\text{atom}}\rangle}\label{5}\tag{absorption of a photon}.$$
In this case there is no photon in the *final* state and remember that my final atomic level is fixed, so what should I do with the density of *final* states to write the transition rate? Although I think that the presence of the photon in the initial state should lead to some continuum and thus to a DoS, I'm not allowed to write a photonic density of final state like \eqref{3} because in my final state I have no photons in this case.
Also, the difference between emission and absorption should only happen due to the **photonic piece of the transition amplitude**, not in the DoS.
So, how do I deal with the DoS in this case?

### Update

Checking Landau&Lifshitz QED (volume 4, section 4: emission and absorption), I noticed that they use Fermi Golden rule in equations $(44.1)$ and $(44.2)$. They say that in the case of emission, the final states lie on a continuum as I've also said in my post. After that, they consider absorption and state only the amplitude is to be replaced, without mentioning the DoS. As its evident from $(44.6)$, they are assuming it is the same. This made the situation even more ambiguous.

---

$^1$ <sub>In other words, we know which atomic states are involved in the transition but not the modes and polarization of the photon.</sub>

Comment: I would think that since there is only *one* final state here (because there is only one vacuum), you don't *need* a density of states.  You only need a density of states when there is a continuum of final-state energies *and* there is a continuum of states "at" the final-state energy, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Density of final states is very singular here (one state), so the derivation of the golden rule need not be valid. The golden rule is a sort of simplification that sometimes makes sense, sometimes it need not (and then we have to go back to more detailed ways of describing the interaction). However, there is still the density of the initial states, so maybe you can derive a variant of the golden rule that gives rate of transition from any of the set of initial states to the single one final state.

Comment: But if the scenario is that there is single photon state and single final state, then yeah, the golden rule looks inapplicable. Then it's safer to go back to equations of motion and derive what expansion coefficients do, and often this does not look like simple jumping between eigenstates, the transition is a continuous and even oscillatory process (Rabi oscillations).

Comment: Atoms jumping from ground state to excited state suggested by the various uses of the golden rule is not really an exact mathematical description, it is more of a simplification of verbal description of the evolution of the psi functions, that for some purposes is enough, but it can't explain all details of light-matter interaction, like excitation by a non-resonant EM wave, Rabi oscillations, etc.

Comment: @JánLalinský I'm glad to see you confirm that what I had in mind is not completely wrong. I also though about density of initial states but not enough to find a way to use it. There is still something off, though. Wouldn't this break the symmetry between absorption and emission (ignoring spontaneous emission, which is caused by a different factor in the amplitude)?

Comment: But in this mode of description, there is no symmetry. When atom gets excited into a band, there is uncertainty in its final state. When it gets deexcited into single state, there is no uncertainty. If we use more detailed description and assume transitions between two eigenstates, that should be quite symmetrical. Fishing from memory, the Einstein coefficient for stimulated absorption is the same as the Einstein coefficient for stimulated emission.

Comment: I see your point there, in the first case (emission) we wrote a single final state and then used the fact that the spectrum is continuous to encode that uncertainty. With the vacuum there is no way to do so, which mean that my original doubt was actually reasonable. Maybe that's why in my lecture notes for the absorption we considered $n\to n-1$ photons instead of $1\to0$.

Comment: Recall how the golden rule is derived - we sum, against the naive desire to apply rules of quantum theory - eigenstate probabilities, not amplitudes, for a class of final states (maybe we could do so for initial states, but this is not usual). This summation of probabilities over many states is what causes the oscillatory evolution of expansion coefficients to produce an increase in the sum probability that is linear in time. If the sum reduces to a single term due to a single final state, there is no suppresion of oscillation and no linear increase in time, there will be oscillations instead.

Comment: When deriving the Einstein coefficients for a pair of states, both for emission and absorption, there has to be summation over a class of different states, or at least different characteristics of the radiation. In non-relativistic semi-classical QT, this is provided by the equilibrium radiation - there is infinity of possible directions and phases of the electric field in equilibrium radiation, and this means to get probability of excitation, or emission, we have to sum over all possibilities. This makes the golden rule viable, I think.

Comment: I think the case of EM radiation being described by a photon state (even if in high $n$) and then atom absorbs it, raises the question whether the golden rule is applicable at all. I am very doubtful, I expect rather Rabi-like behaviour, oscillations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case there is no photon in the final state and remember that my final atomic level is fixed...

No, the final level is *not* fixed. (At least not in the Fermi's Golden Rule expression, which is the right way to think about things--and how things might get "fixed".)

You must *sum over* final states in Fermi's Golden Rule, which in this case include a sum over all the electronic states (and no photon states, since there is no photon).

Your delta function in Fermi's Golden Run will take care of energy conservation, but you still must do the sum over all final states (which in this case is all the electronic states).

> so what should I do with the density of final states to write the transition rate?

Use the electronic density of states.

---

If you want an answer in terms of equations, Consider Fermi's Golden Rule in the following form:
$$
R = 2\pi\sum_f |\langle\psi_f|\langle 0|H_1|\psi_0\rangle|\vec k,\epsilon\rangle|^2\delta(E_0+\hbar\omega - E_f)\;,
$$

This leads to an expression for the absorption cross section $\sigma(\omega)$ as follows:
$$
\sigma(\omega) = \frac{4\pi^2e^2\omega}{c}\sum_f|\langle \psi_f|\epsilon^*\cdot \vec r |\psi_0\rangle|^2\delta(E_0 + \hbar\omega - E_f)\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $\vec r$ is the position operator of the sample electron and $-e$ is the electronic charge.

That sum over $f$ you see in Eq. (1) is a sum over the electronic states of the sample.

---

**Update:**

Below is an example. Caveat: In the example I ignore electron spin degeneracy.

Suppose that the incident light polarization $\vec \epsilon$ can be chosen such that $\vec \epsilon\cdot\vec r = z$. Suppose further that the initial states is the 1s orbital. Then the matrix element selects final states with $\ell=1$ and $m=0$.

Eq. (1) becomes:
$$
\sigma(\omega) = \frac{4\pi^2e^2\omega}{c}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}|\langle \psi_{n,1,0}|z|\psi_{1,0,0}\rangle|^2\delta(E_{n=1} + \hbar\omega - E_n)\;,
$$
where $E_n = \frac{-13.6\;\text{eV}}{n^2}$.

For an isolated hydrogen atom, this spectrum look like isolated peaks (the delta functions) at energies where the photon energy $\hbar\omega$ can cause transitions "up" from the 1s state to the np states (2p, 3p, 4p, etc).

For a solid, the isolated delta-function peaks are modified into "absorption edges," which pop up roughly at the atomic transition frequencies, but are not delta functions. The absorption edges have structure due to interatomic factors and broadening due to quasi-particle lifetime, core-hole, and other multi-particle effects that are often swept under the rug in a single quasi-particle picture.

Comment: I said the final level is fixed because I imagined a transition between two specific atomic levels by means of a photon absorption (e.g. $\lvert 1 0 0\rangle\to\lvert 2 1 0\rangle for hydrogen); in such case the only part to be determined would be the *photon* energy, but maybe the problem at hand is that I'm reasoning the other way around. The photon energy should be known from the beginning as it is in the initial state, so the problem should be fixing the atomic level in the case of absorption, right?

Comment: What about the symmetry between absorption and emission (cf. last paragraph of my question)? This way - which I consider fine - the DoS are different.

Comment: "...but maybe the problem at hand is that I'm reasoning the other way around." Yes. The photon energy and the initial state energy restrict the energy of the final state via the delta function that is already explicitly in Fermi's golden rule. This does *not* necessarily limit you to a *single* final state, since more than one state can have the same energy (even in hydrogen). Yes, you are effectively limited in some sense to only final states that are accessible, but that all comes out naturally from Fermi's Golden Rule.

Comment: The final states in emission are clearly different (for example you need to account for the final photon states). The initial state in emission is also potentially different. For example, you can not emit a photon if you atom is already in the 1s state, but you can absorb a photon.

Comment: Sure there is some relation/symmetry between absorption and emission, since the matrix elements are the same. But the final densities of states are not the same. This is basically similar to what Einstein considered a long time ago: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind. Suppose I want to calculate the transition rate for e.g. hydrogen, while in the case of absorption I get a number (cf. my equation), in the case of absorption the DoS is a sum of delta distributions as you've correctly pointed out. So in such case, after I'm done calculating $R$, I'll need to integrate over some initial frequencies to eliminate the $\delta$ functions to get something finite.

Comment: There is a small typo in equation (1). The subscript of the last energy variable in the delta function should be $E_f$ instead of $E_m$.

Comment: @Mr.Feynman The dirac delta function is replaced with a spectral lineshape function in this case. I.e. replace the dirac delta with a Gaussian, Lorentz or Voigt function centered on the transition energy. Then you can do the discrete sum over final states of the hydrogen and obtain a finite number. Fermi's Golden rule requires additional input, either in the form of the density or a lineshape function based on the lifetime of the final state. The dirac delta expression is not a rate, as you correctly noted.

Comment: @HansWurst I fixed the typo, thanks!

Comment: In order to get a transition rate, don't we need to integrate over a distribution of photon energies? I'm thinking of the mantra "average over initial states, sum over final states" -- here the "average over initial states" needs to include the distribution of photon initial states.

Comment: Here we are assuming the initial state is fixed. If you would like to average over initial states, you can. For example, it is fairly typical to average over the polarizations. But in this example we assume a fixed photon initial state and fixed electron initial state.